# Problem with MS Access and calculating Average of a Column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this MS Access query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Career.careerId, Student.studentName, Avg([Student-Topic].grade), Career.careerName
FROM 
    Career INNER JOIN 
        (
        (Student INNER JOIN [Student-Topic] 
            ON Student.studentId = [Student-Topic].studentId) 
                INNER JOIN [Student-Career] 
                    ON Student.studentId = [Student-Career].studentId) 
        ON Career.careerId = [Student-Career].careerId
WHERE 
    (((
        [Student-Career].careerId)=[Career].[careerId]) AND 
        (([Student-Topic].studentId)=[Student].[studentId]));
```

Without the Avg function the query works fine, but when I place it, it breaks down...

What's my error?

Comment: What does "breaks down" mean?  An error message would be really helpful.  Since you are using an aggregate function, you most likely need a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 4):

Does this query express the averages you're looking for?

```
SELECT studentId, Avg(grade) AS average_grade
FROM [Student-Topic]
GROUP BY studentId;
```

If so, you could save it as a separate query and JOIN it with your original query.  Or include it within the original query as a subquery.

**Edit**:  Oops.  A subquery could be problematic since the table name must be bracketed ... that can confuse Access' query designer when it uses square brackets around a subquery.  Better to give the table a name which doesn't require bracketing ... Student_Topic instead of Student-Topic.

Answer (score 3):

you must group your data when using aggregate functions.

- i.e. add a GROUP BY clause.